# UIView animateWithDuration en Swift 4

Tags: swift, objective-c

tengo este código en Objective-C y quiero pasarlo a Swift 4.

¿Alguien me puede indicar la forma más sencilla?

Estoy empezando con el lenguaje y estoy un poco perdido, gracias.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
           animations:^{
               datePicker.alpha = 0.0f;
           }
           completion:^(BOOL finished){
               datePicker.hidden = YES;
           }];
```

Comment: Hola Shadros. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Los cambios de ObjC a Swift y al revés suelen ser muy sencillos porque   son casi iguales, comienza con UIView.animate y ya te auto completara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que adjuntaste se vería de la siguiente manera en swift 4

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
    datePicker.alpha = 0
 }) { (_) in
    datePicker.hidden = true
 }
```